# Can the role of objects in programming be compared to how higher order components work in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop

I am new to programming and after some learning of JS, I decided to do some React. Frankly, during my study of OOP, I couldn't properly understand the concept of objects thus decided to keep my learning with the hope that later I would figure out this concept. Later, I encountered the concept of HOC in React which basically helps us to reuse a certain logic in our React app, that is, if we have a hover logic used in several places, it is when we create HOC and reuse it wherever that hover logic is used. My sole and main question is Are objects in object-oriented programming work the same way, that is, whenever we have a certain logic used in several places, we need to create an object which is then reused. Can I consider that object in OOP is like HOC in React?

Comment: Not really, React components are objects and even though HOCs are objects, they are more like inheritance in OOP.

Comment: @Titus, thank you for your kind comments. I meant to say, imagine we have one certain logic(no matter what) which is used in, say, 5 places. Is it true that in OOP instead of repeating the same logic in 5 places we create an object containing that very logic which we can reuse in that 5 places by instantiating the object. So, basically objects are LIKE HOC in React. Because HOC also contains logic which we can reuse. Is it true?

Comment: No, you'll create components, you will create HOCs if you want to add the same logic to components of different kinds, for instance, if you want to display an image and some text in multiple places, you'll create a component (reuse logic), if you want components of different kinds to be wrapped into a `<div>`, you'll create a HOC (still logic reuse but of higher order).

Answer (score 0):

Object Oriented Programming relies on inheritance as a technique to share code between objects in a parent-child hierarchy. The strict tree-like nature of a parent-child hierarchy means that it's not uncommon to run into the ["diamond problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem).

[image]

In this example, `Scanner` and `Printer` inherit from `PoweredDevice`. `Copier` needs to share the behaviour of both `Scanner` and `Printer` but in most object oriented programming languages you aren't allowed to inherit from two parents.

Other languages and libraries favour a technique called *composition*, as an alternative to inheritance. React falls into this category. You can define as many reusable behaviours as you want with higher-order components and then apply them all to a component.

```js
function Copier() {
  return (
    // ...
  )
}

export default withScanner(withPrinter(App)))
```

You're still creating a hierarchy, but you're creating them dynamically at runtime. There's no static rule that says `withPrinter` has to be a child of `withPoweredDevice`—unlike traditional inheritance where you have to define the hierarchy when you author the class (before compilation).

The React docs even provide a document that addresses ["composition vs inheritance"](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) which is a great place to carry on reading to understand the differences between the two paradigms.

To conclude:

- Both OOP and HOC enable code-reuse
- OOP class can only extend from one parent
- React components can be wrapped with any number of HOCs
- OOP only allows reuse along static compile-time hierarchies
- HOCs enables reuse across dynamic run time hierarchies

Comment: thank you Dan for your kind answer. The reason for asking the question was to properly understand objects and why should we care about them in OOP? So, is it true that objects in OOP wraps a certain logic which we can reuse over and over instead of copy and pasting that logic in several places. So, the benefits will be if we find bug in that logic code we just need to change one place(which is object) then all of the places where that object was used will be changed automatically. Is that true?

Comment: please Dan I really need your help

Comment: Yes, it's true that you can share code in OOP through inheritance and that means that fixing a bug in a parent class will fix the same bug in all the child classes.